# Is there Optional in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, option-type

I'm wondering why there is no optional (not necessary from Java 8) in Hibernate? It looks like good way to implement lazy OneToOne relation. Instead hibernate suggest to enable byte-code manipulation to achieve lazy one to one.

Comment: Why not annotate with: @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)

Comment: Of course there is annotation @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) and @Basic(optional = true), but they do not work together. Hibernate will ignore lazy and query imminently. Hibernate have to know if optional fields contains null or object, because it cannot create proxy of null.

Answer (score 0):

There is an 'optional' parameter. 
`@Basic(optional = true)` above the column.

"Defines whether the value of the field or property may be null. This is a hint and is disregarded for primitive types; it may be used in schema generation. If not specified, defaults to  true."

source: https://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/Basic/optional